# S3 bucket access for authorized users

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

S3 bucket i want to save object such as image or video and want it to be protected and can access by authorised users only what should i do. One way is making url with token for particular time expired it after some time. Is any other way also to doing this.

Comment: Please clarify what it is you would like to accomplish that can't already be accomplished using a signed object URL. Do you need additional restrictions? If so, what are they? Stuff like that.

Comment: I want to send restricted url of object to api but i want to make sure nobody can able to download the object using url . But he can access the object inside application only.

Answer (score 3):

Objects in Amazon S3 are private by default.

If you wish to only grant access to specific files to authorized users, you have a couple of options:

- Use AWS credentials, or
- Use pre-signed URLs

If you wish your application to be able to access the objects, you can give **AWS credentials** to your application. This could either be as an **IAM User** (applications can be *Users* too), or via an **IAM Role** that the application assumes (eg assign the Role to an EC2 instance and the application is then automatically provided with credentials). You would then **grant permissions** to the IAM User/Role to access a particular bucket, or a path within the bucket.

Alternatively, if you wish to grant selective access to particular objects (eg a user's photos), you can use **pre-signed URLs**. These are time-limited credentials that provide access to an Amazon S3 object. An application can **generate the pre-signed URL with a couple of lines of code**. The URL can then be inserted into web pages (eg in `<img>` tags) to provide temporary access to private objects. When the time period **expires**, the URL will no longer function.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a solution which allows your system to access an AWS S3 object's contents internally without the need to assign an access token to the object.

```
<?php

if (!defined('MY_AWS_AUTOLOADER_FILE_LOCATION')) {
  // Replace /var/www/html/aws/aws-autoloader.php with wherever your actual file is
  // Make sure you've already downloaded and unzipped the aws-autoloader.php file
  // Can be found at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/download/aws.zip
  define('MY_AWS_AUTOLOADER_FILE_LOCATION', '/var/www/html/aws/aws-autoloader.php');
}

if (!defined('MY_AWS_REGION_ID')) {
  // Replace us-west-2 with whatever your actual region ID is
  define('MY_AWS_REGION_ID', 'us-west-2');
}

if (!defined('MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')) {
  // Replace abcdefghijk with whatever your actual access key is
  define('MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'abcdefghijk');
}

if (!defined('MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')) {
  // Replace lmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789 with whatever your actual secret key is
  define('MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', 'lmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789');
}


// Set the required environmental variables in case they
// haven't already been set in .htaccess or elsewhere
putenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=' . MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID);
putenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=' . MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);


// Register the s3:// stream wrapper
aws_register_stream_wrapper();


// Now, the URI of an S3 object can be accessed internally, without having assigned
// a special access token to it. Assuming your bucket's name is my-bucket and the
// object's file key inside that bucket is images/example.jpg you can build
// the object's URI like so, which would assign a value of
//   s3://my-bucket/images/example.jpg
// to $object_uri (making it internally accessible via that same URI):
$object_uri = aws_render_s3_uri('my-bucket', 'images/example.jpg');


/**
 * Registers the s3:// stream wrapper
 */
function aws_register_stream_wrapper() {
  $region = MY_AWS_REGION_ID;
  // Simple security checks in case someone has messed with something
  // they shouldn't have
  if (!empty($region) && is_string($region)) {
    $client = aws_render_s3_client();
    $client->registerStreamWrapper();
  }
}


/**
 * @param $version (string)
 *   The version of the AWS API to use
 *
 * @return (object)
 *   An AWS S3 client
 */
function aws_render_s3_client($version = 'latest') {
  require_once(MY_AWS_AUTOLOADER_FILE_LOCATION);
  $s3_client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'key' => MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    'secret' => MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    'region' => MY_AWS_REGION_ID,
    'version' => $version,
  ]);
  return $s3_client;
}


/**
 * @param $bucket (string)
 *   The name of the AWS bucket in which $file_key resides
 *
 * @param $file_key (string)
 *   The name of the file to be retrieved, relative to the AWS bucket
 *
 * @return (string)
 *   The URL to an AWS S3 object URL using the s3:// stream wrapper
 */
function aws_render_s3_uri($bucket, $file_key) {
  $uri = "s3://{$bucket}/{$file_key}";
  return $uri;
}
```

Comment: @pawansgi92 Hope it helps... The solution in and of itself should be ready to use. :)